# Issue with jQuery :not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a search icon that when hovered over reveals an input text search box. I'm using jQuery to add a class to the input to reveal the text box when the search icon is hovered over. That is working fine.

The next function is that if the user decides not to click in the search box and elsewhere on the page, the search box goes away. That's working fine too.

The only remaining issue is that if the user clicks in the search box, it also goes away which I don't want.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-text text-hidden" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." value="" size="15" id="edit-search-block-form-1" name="search_block_form" maxlength="128">

<input type="image" src="http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/large/802431483.png?1377197793" class="form-submit search-hover" alt="Search" id="edit-submit">
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".search-hover").hover(function () {
    $('.text-hidden').addClass('hover');
  });

  // Now remove the class in case of a false start or the user decides to do something else.
  $("body:not(.text-hidden)").click(function(){
      //alert('The body click is working!!!');
    $('.form-text.text-hidden').removeClass('hover');
  });
```

Note that I'm attempting to use the `:not` selector to indicate to only remove the `hover` class if clicked anywhere but the search box but it's not working.

[I've got a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/xCsCM/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    $(".search-hover").hover(function () {
        $('.text-hidden').addClass('hover');
    });

    // Now remove the class in case of a false start or the user decides to do something else.
    $("body").click(function(e){
        //alert('The body click is working!!!');
        if($(e.target).closest('.text-hidden').length == 0)
            $('.form-text.text-hidden').removeClass('hover');
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/urWgm/)

Comment: Excellent, so it looks like `e.target` is shorthand for `event.target`? Very nice. I'm curious what the `length == 0` does in this as well.

Comment: @DannyEnglander `e` is the parameter name accepting the event object in the callback method... if you name the parameter `event` then you need to use `event.target`

Comment: @DannyEnglander here we checks whether the actual target of the click event or one of its ancestor element has the class `text-hidden`, so `$(e.target).closest('.text-hidden')` will try to find such an element then we checks the length of the result to see whether it actually found one

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you click the input, the *body's click event* still arises.

There's a simple solution. Just stop the [event's propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) when the input's being clicked.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xCsCM/22/)

```
$(".form-text.text-hidden").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

P.S - Notice that I've removed the `:not selector` from the JS. It has become unnecessary.

Comment: Good one, I like this solution too.